# How to call javascript function in VB.NET mvc controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net-2010

I have a mvc application. I am trying to call a javascript function (say Create) in the controller action code...my idea here is that when a user hits http://localhost/somecontroller/someaction/id.. the controller should run the Create function..in this function i am using xhrget to get the information from a webservice and it writes to the view..now my question is how do i call the Create function in the controller

here is the Create function

```
Create: function (obj)
{
var xhrGet1 = dXhr.get({
                url: "http://localhost/SomeService/parameter?id=" + obj.id,
                handleAs: "json",
                headers: { 'accept': 'application/json' }
            });
---
---
---
}
```

Here is how i started the controller and not able to move forward with this...Any ideas?

```
Function somecontroller (id As string) As ...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to directly call the `Create` function that presumably lives in your client-side javascript code using `somecontroller`, you'll want to do something like this in your `ActionResult` method that intercepts the initial request that lives in `somecontroller`:

```
ViewBag.Id = id
```

And then in your `.cshtml` view you would have to add this function on your page load (either `$(document).ready() { ... }` with jQuery or simply `window.onload = function() { ... }`:

```
someObj.Create({id: @ViewBag.Id});
```

*BUT* there are better ways to do this. One simple solution may be to simply call the `http://localhost/SomeService/` in your controller and pass the result as a strongly-typed model to your view?

Comment: Thank you TimDog...with this "One simple solution may be to simply call the http://localhost/SomeService/ in your controller and pass the result" actually the service is a rest service and i cant add the reference in the project and generate a proxy to use. How do i call the service directly in the controller in this scenario?

Comment: look up these third party libraries: `hammock` or `restsharp` to make it easy on yourself to call RESTful services from .NET. (no proxies involved)